# can i manupulate my layout page at run time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

my part of _layout.cshtml is below

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
   @Html.Partial("_LeftSide")
</div>
```

can i change "_LeftSide" to "_LeftSide2" at run time?

Comment: Of course you can. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes you can, on server and in your studio. the only think you have to do is save changes, and refresh your page, this will do this trick.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could do something like

```
@Html.Partial(someCondition ? "LeftSide" : "LeftSide2")
```

Comment: yes its so simple,but i have imagined thats its need a someting like a event mechanism :)